# Cannot Login to SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-sbs

I'm hoping someone has an answer for me... I installed a new Microsoft SBS 2008 server last week and everything appeared to be working normally. I went to reboot the server yesterday to finish the install for Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 and upon reboot could no longer login to the server via either RDP or local console. The error message I get states that there are no logon servers available to service the logon request.

I'm able to login to the server fine via Safe Mode with Networking but cannot login via a normal method. The server is currently at SP1. I attempted to install SP2 inside of safe mode after enabling the installation services via a registry edit but the install failed and rolled back after 2 or 3 hours.

It appears that one of the services is not starting for some reason. I believe it's LSASS but can't actually login to see the active services during a normal boot. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you get to the event viewer remotely, from another server? This may give some insight to what errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some bad software in there somewhere (since it works in safe mode fine). Login to safe mode, run msconfig. Disable all non-Microsoft services and startup items. Reboot. If you can login fine now, try reenabling services and startup items until you find which one is causing your issue.

This is pretty much standard Microsoft procedure. If you called them up about this problem, they'd have you do the same thing.

Comment: Hi Jason, Sorry, should have mentioned that in the original post. I did the Microsoft clean boot and disabled everything except for the MS services. Still no luck.